# .htaccess to defined routing for php system

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i have a php based system that uses this setup at the moment

## .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

## PHP

```
<?php
$route = explode('/',(isset($_GET["route"]))? $_GET["route"]:"home");
...
some other stuff based on route parts
...
$route = implode("/", $route);
... 
#load content
include(includes/$route/index.php);
```

and this sends and request to route so

```
domain.net/this/is/the/page => route = this/is/the/page
domain.net/this/page => route = this/page
domain.net/page => route = page
```

and then from this php will load a file from the includes folder and that controls the content of the system.

```
$route = this/is/the/page => loads => includes/this/is/the/page/index.php
$route = this/page => loads => includes/this/page/index.php
$route = page => loads => includes/page/index.php
```

and so on this works great for my system but i have had thoughts on expanding this more dynamically so if i want dynamic duplicate of it i can just create a new includes folder sort of thing

so my question to the wonderful people of StackOverflow how can i go about this my thinking of it is

```
domain.net/{copy}/{this/is/the/page}
//would output this
$server = copy;
$route = this/is/the/page

domain.net/{copy2}/{this/page}
//would output this
$server = copy2;
$route = this/is/the/page

domain.net/{copy2}/{this/page}
//would output this
$server = copy2;
$route = this/page    

domain.net/{copy2}/{page}
//would output this
$server = copy2;
$route = page
```

so the first one is say $server and all trailing after that is the path $route

```
domain.net/[server]/[path/to/file]
```

thus making managing the system with multiple versions of it easier for me.

other than that all i can think of is just making a new domain and copying it to that domain location and just make all the adjustments needed for that version of it for the client.

am i just thinks crazy or can this be done.

Comment: What is your motivation for using mod_rewrite in this way? Mostly mod_rewrite is used to avoid having a script for every url. Normally all urls are rewritten to index.php which gets the original url from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and processes it to load dynamic content accordingly.

Comment: as its only the content that changes with this it makes it easier to call the content file from a function which in turn inserts any other dynamic content into this page as well as having the ability to call functions within a php class. if it works don't knock it.